# How to convert this from nginx to haproxy

Tags: nginx, configuration, haproxy, proxypass

How can I write this proxy pass example from nginx:
*code one:*

```
location /appDir/ {
        proxy_pass https://Name/appDir/;
    }
```

to haproxy?

additionally:
the below is from haproxy site.
*code two:*

```
 # ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://bk.dom.com/bar
 http-request set-header Host bk.dom.com
 reqirep  ^([^ :]*)\ /mirror/foo/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```

But where does /bar go from the commented-out part?

Answer (score 0):

```
reqirep ^([^ :]*)\ /mirror/foo/(.*)     \1\ /bar/\2
```

This would transform this:

```
GET /mirror/foo/baz HTTP/1.1
```

...into this...

```
GET /bar/baz HTTP/1.1
```

...which appears to be what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you also provide for 'code one' above?

Comment: @Zodzie `Could you also provide for 'code one' above?` Maybe give it a shot first and report back if you have some issues.

Comment: It should be as simple as `use_backend foo if { path_beg /appDir/ }`, where `foo` is a backend with the appropriate server(s).  Hard to say without more context.

Comment: @GregL Are people really allowed to post comments like that on this site? What makes you think I hadn't tried everything I could and this site wasn't my last resort? 

Anyway, it's likely michael is correct, but here is what i used:

    `acl namedFunction url_sub foundWithinUrl_sub` followed by 
    `use_backend <backend name> if namedFunction`

And in backend <backend name> I have `backend backendName` followed by `mode http` and `server <servername> <parameters>`

Comment: @Zodzie, If you have an issue with my comment, flag it for moderator attention. In any event, I was simply asking whether you had tried resolving the issue yourself, based on Michael's answer. I haven't been around SF that long, but one thing I've picked up is that the community expects you to have tried what you can before posting here and then including information about those attempts in your question. It serves to show that you've put some effort into the problem as opposed to looking for a quick answer. Simply saying  *give me what I asked for* doesn't tend to be a well-received approach.

Comment: @Zodzie I don't believe the comment was intended to be malicious in any way, and I seconded it. The point was not that we necessarily assumed you hadn't tried -- though that does happen -- but rather since we can't see what you're trying, it's difficult to find the problem and craft answers that will steer you -- and future visitors who find this question -- in the correct direction.  When asked for clarification, it's optimum if you edit the original question, since more than 1 line of code-in-comments is tricky to follow.  Does testing `path_beg` in an anonymous `{` `}` acl do what you need?